# Rendering text colored Unicode emojis in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to render a [monochrome unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F916/) robot in Chrome, but it will only render a colored one no matter what I try.

Every hit I've found so far is for people complaining about it being in mono when they want color! My use case is for a small status bar - I want to show whether or not automation is working.

I'm using Chromium v101.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#try_it tried these?

Answer (score 0):

CSS filter can have a grayscale value:

```css
div {
  font-size: 48px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill them with a solid color:

```css
div {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: transparent;  
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or you can outline them:

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px blue;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<div title=""></div>
```